# Como inserir dados de uma query do banco de dados em uma página html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Preciso inserir os dados de uma query do banco de dados em uma página html. No momento em que o usuário apertar o botão gerar pdf os dados digitados pelo mesmo serão capturados em um contrato em formato html. Alguém tem uma sugestão de como inserir os dados de um banco de dados em uma página html ?

Comment: Cara achei sua pergunta um pouco vaga. Voce tem duvida na parte da query mysql no php? ou a dúvida é so na hora de imprimir os dados na tela?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo adquirir os valores do formulário para o relatório em php converter para pdf eu uso html2pdf.

Comment: Fechei esta pergunta como duplicata da outra por entender que seu objetivo final é o que está na outra pergunta. Por favor avise se eu estiver enganado.